# Is cell value between any of a set of non-consecutive ranges?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup, vlookup

I have a column of data representing the time stamp of all events that occurred in computer-task (ranging from 0s to 380s) for a psychology experiment.

I am trying to ascertain whether any of the recorded event times occurred during the presentation of the fixation cross.

The fixation cross was presented every 2.5 seconds (starting at 0), and lasted for 1 second. So, the fixation crosses were presented between 0 - 1, 2.5 - 3.5, 5 - 6.5 etc, until 382.5-383.5 .

Is there a way to, for example, use LOOKUP to see if each event-time lies between any fixation cross range? I can only think of writing a huge IF AND formula for this at the moment i.e., IF event-time is equal to, or greater than 0s and less than 1s, then that was during the 1st fixation cross, ALL the way to the last fixation cross! e.g.:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=B2,A2< C2),TRUE,IF(AND(A2>=B3,A2< C3),TRUE,....IF(AND(A2>=B150,A2< C150),TRUE,)
```

(with A = event time; B & C = fixation cross start- and end-time, respectively)

This obviously can't be the most efficient way!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [MOD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx) you can peel out the remainder of a 'divide-by-2.5' math operation. If the remainder is 1 second or less, it seems to fall into your time window. If you are just looking for TRUE or FALSE, you don't need the [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb), just the criteria.

```
=MOD(A1, 2.5)<=1
```

I'm not sure of the true nature of your values. That *1* might have to be `TIME(0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Works perfectly, so simple and efficient! Thanks very much!